# Use references/pointers to JS Array declared outside of function

Tags: javascript, angular, this, immutability, mutability

I am writing a small tictactoe game in Angular.

I have a function `checkForWin()` which checks all the possible winning combinations for a win. (Horizontal, Vertical, and Diagonal)

The function works correctly when I declare/init `potentialWinningCombos` inside of   `checkForWin()`

```
checkForWin(){
  for(let combo of potentialWinningCombos){  
    let potentialWinningCombos: string[][] = [
       //Horizontal
       [this.gb[0][0], this.gb[0][1], this.gb[0][2]],
       [this.gb[1][0], this.gb[1][1], this.gb[1][2]],
...
```

So that's fine and all, but my original design was to declare/init `potentialWinningCombos` outside of   `checkForWin()` (in the component -- and of course I'd iterate over `this.potentialWinningCombos` instead of the local variable)

With this approach I always get empty strings (the initial values).

My original thought was that when I declare/init `potentialWinningCombos` with a reference to `this.gb[0][0]`, then it would simply be a reference, but it seems that is not the case...

Why?
Additionally, is there any possible way to keep my original design (using a reference/pointer) so the object isn't recreated everytime `checkForWin()` is called? (I know here it's no big deal, but imagine another case where this is a massive object...)

Comment: Where you init the `potentialWinningCombos` when you put it in your component? You can create a initfunction, and call it when declare the variable, or put the initial code in `constructor()`

Comment: Please provide more code snippet with reproducibility